# How to change default field in a segmentation list table

Tags: pardot

Is there a way to change the default columns of the table in a segmentation list overview? I'd like to show a custom field and remove columns I have no use for.

I saw how to do that on the Prospect List (http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2128079-prospect-list-overview#customizing-the-table). I'd like to do the exact same thing for my segmentation lists.

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

Pardot product team have been rolling out updated table functionality. It hasn't been rolled out to all tables yet!